# List of file paths in excel. Want to extract the filename from paths, so everything after the LAST "\" in the file path

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been trying to use a combination of Excel's =RIGHT function with FIND. I guess my thinking is:

Example:

I have "H:\NIck\Pictures\Fam\download.jpg" in cell A1

I would like to then write a formula that would take the end "download.jpg" and drop it into A2.

My thinking so far:

1. Start looking from the end of the cell text.
2. When excel runs into the first instance of "\" , extract everything up until that point into cell A2.

Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this page](https://trumpexcel.com/find-characters-last-position/) that does it for URLS.
It gives a good breakdown and explains the different parts of the formula.
Just change the character you need to look for to be the back-slash, and it will work for filenames.

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))),1))
```

Comment: Hi, this definitely solves my problem. I'm going to dig into it to understand it more. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @BlueGI, probably best to add content to your answer rather than link to external content. Link-only (or almost link-only, like yours) answers are likely to be downvoted and possibly flagged.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're not using an ancient version of Office, InstrRev makes it simpler to find the last \ in the file name.  It parses the string right to left instead of left to right (as Instr does).

Try this:

```
Sub TestExtract()
    Debug.Print ExtractFilename("H:\Nick\Pictures\Fam\download.jpg")
    Debug.Print ExtractFilename("H:\Fam\download.jpg")
    Debug.Print ExtractFilename("H:\download.jpg")
    Debug.Print ExtractFilename("H:download.jpg")

End Sub

Function ExtractFilename(sFullPath As String) As String

    Dim x As Long

    If InStr(sFullPath, "\") > 0 Then
        x = InStrRev(sFullPath, "\")
        ExtractFilename = Mid$(sFullPath, x + 1)
    Else
        ' Might be a fullpath like C:somefile.xxx
        If InStr(sFullPath, ":") > 0 Then
            x = InStr(sFullPath, ":")
            ExtractFilename = Mid$(sFullPath, x + 1)
        End If
        ' Other oddities?  Handle 'em here
    End If

End Function
```